# Бот discord не банит участника, и выдает ошибку (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Бот discord должен банить участника если тот напишет запрещенное слово но вместо этого он просто выдает ошибку

```
Ignoring exception in command TEST:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\epicb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
   packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\epicb\Desktop\папки\плюшки\мой ботяра\2 — копия.py", line 22, in TEST
    await bot.ban(author.mention)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'ban'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\epicb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
   packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "C:\Users\epicb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
   packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\epicb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
   packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 
'Bot' 
    object 
    has no attribute 'ban'
```

код:

```
@bot.command() 
async def TEST(ctx): 
    author = ctx.message.author
    await bot.ban(author.mention)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'The banhammer has awoken! {user.name} has been banished')
    await ctx.guild.ban(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

что же ты бота банишь?

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f"**{member}** был забанен по причине `{reason}`!")
```